# omnetpp: reading module parameters

Tags: omnet++

I have the following module defined in a ned file:

```
 @namespace(cbsdsim);
 simple SASSim {
     parameters:
         @class(SASSim);
         int maxCbsdsPerSas = 10;
 }
```

I create the module by calling the following (from another module):

```
cModuleType* sasSimModType = cModuleType::find("SASSim");
sasSimModType->setName("SASSim");
char* name = "SAS.1";
SASSim* sasSimMod = (SASSim*) sasSimModType->create(name,parent);
```

The constructor for SASSim gets called. Here is the constructor:

```
SASSim::SASSim() {

cout << " SASSim::SASSim" << endl;
//this->finalizeParameters();
int cbsdFanIn = par("maxCbsdPerSas");
 .....
}
```

However omnetpp is unhappy about calling par(...) in the code fragment above. I get an exception and a confusing error message:

```
  what():  (omnetpp::cModule): Object has no associated cComponentType (maybe omnetpp::cModule is not derived from cModule/cChannel?)
```

Indeed when I add this->getNumParams() in the constructor it returns 0. If I hard code the parameter, the initialization works fine so I assume I need to do something in order to load the parameters. I could, presumably put the parameters in omnetpp.ini or elsewhere but I would like to know why this does not work.Do I have to do something prior to calling create to load the params? Thanks,

Comment: It appears I can only read the params after initialize(). So if I call par() in the initialize() method, I am able to read the params. So any setup like gate allocations based on reading a module parameter can only be done after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the parameters after initialization - not in the constructor of the Module. This is a bit strange because creating cGates etc. works fine from the constructor.